# Can I get rid of the top bar in Flexdashboards?

Tags: html, css, r, ggplot2, flexdashboard

I have a flex dashboard and I'd like to get rid of the top bar.

I've tried to do this with CSS by setting the height to 0px, but I've not been successful.

This is my code (it'll be long since it's flex dashboards)

````
    ---
    title: "Flex"
    author: "I"
    output: 
      flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
        orientation: rows
    ---
    
    <style>                     
    .navbar {
      background-color:white;
      border-color:white;
    }
    
    .navbar-brand {
      color:white!important;
    }
    
    .navbar-brand {
      color:white!important;
    }
    
    a {
      background-color:white!important;
    }
    
    li {
      background-color:white!important;
    }
    
    body {
      background-color:white;
      border-color:white;
    }
    
    .chart-title {
      background-color:white;
      color:white;
      border-color:white;
    }
    
    #section-chart1 {
      background-color:white;
      border-color:white;
    }
    
    </style>  
    
    ```{r setup, include=FALSE}
    library(ggplot2)
    library(plotly)
    library(plyr)
    library(flexdashboard)
    library(hrbrthemes)
    
    # Make some noisily increasing data
    set.seed(955)
    dat <- data.frame(cond = rep(c("A", "B"), each=10),
                      xvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3),
                      yvar = 1:20 + rnorm(20,sd=3))
    
    ```{}

    Page One
    =======================================================================
    
    Row
    -----------------------------------------------------------------------
    
    ### chart1
    
    
    ```{r}
    p <-
      iris %>% 
        ggplot(aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width)) +
                  geom_point(size = 2, color = "purple") +
                  theme_ipsum_rc(grid = "XY") +
                  labs(title = "Sepal Length by sepal width")
    
    ggplotly(p)
````

You can ignore the {} at the end of the first code block. I added it there so stack overflow would keep the whole thing as a single code block.

I've used the CSS to successfully make it invisible, and now I'd like to get rid of it altogether.

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example or demo?

Comment: You can use that code block in RStudio and run this code rsconnect::deployApp("filename.Rmd")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set `.navbar` to `display: none` the navbar won't be displayed and setting `body` to `padding-top: 0;` will help you get rid of the spacing.

```
.navbar {
  display:none;
}

body {
  padding-top: 0;
}
```

Comment: It got rid of the bar, but there's still the empty space in its place. Can I get rid of the empty space?